# Images cut off in older android browser

Tags: android, responsive-design, cross-browser, responsive-images

I'm working on a responsive design and have made the images' code as such - looks great on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

```
img {
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

However, on the old Android browsers, v2.3.4, it doesn't work and the images are cut off. Is there a rule or trick to making images for old browsers responsive? Thanks for anyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting max-width as the second argument? Remember these are cascading rules so one will override the other.

```
img {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've applied this rule and still nothing. It only happens in the area where I use a table. I made two columns using tables, but I think I may need to switch over to divs. Thanks for your help!